# Why does this simple pspicture fail to compile?

Tags: pspicture

A long time ago, I draw this (and many other) simple `pspictures`. I have been trying to compile them again in order to modify them, only to find that now they all fail to compile. I do not know what may have happened.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage{pspicture} % To draw plots.

% FIGURE ITSELF %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

%\pagecolor{white}

\psset{unit=0.1mm}
\begin{pspicture}(85,-25)(765,250)
\putbranch(300,240)(2,1){200}
\egalhshift=0
\iib{}{$p_1$}{$p_2$}[c][$1$][]
\putbranch(500,140)(2,1){250}
\egalhshift=0
\iiib{}{$0.1$}{$0.89$}{$0.01$}[c][$5$][$1$][$0$]
\end{pspicture}
    
\end{document}
```

**Can anybody tell me the reason why such a figure fails to compile?** I suspect that whatever is preventing this figure from compiling is preventing all my `pspictures`from compiling. Since I have many of such figures, spotting the reason why they all fail to compile would prevent me from drawing them from scratch and would be enormously beneficial and time-saving.

Comment: I'd say you are loading the wrong package.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I suspect I may have unknowingly changed the original preamble... What package shouldI load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the name, the package `pspicture` has nothing to do with the environment of the same name. A quick internet search of the macros shows that you need the package `egameps`, which in turns need something out of the `pstricks` bundle but is apparently too lazy to load it itself. Using `pst-all` seems to work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{egameps}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.1mm}
\begin{pspicture}(85,-25)(765,250)
\putbranch(300,240)(2,1){200}
\egalhshift=0
\iib{}{$p_1$}{$p_2$}[c][$1$][]
\putbranch(500,140)(2,1){250}
\egalhshift=0
\iiib{}{$0.1$}{$0.89$}{$0.01$}[c][$5$][$1$][$0$]
\end{pspicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Overleaf rejects to compile... Any idea why?

Comment: @Héctor Maybe wrong compiler? `pstricks` works of course with `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`. It should work out of the box with `xelatex`, or you can try and add the package `auto-pst-pdf` for `pdflatex`, but you'll need `--shell-escape`. But I never used Overleaf so I don't know what is possible or not.

Comment: You're right: wrong compiler. Thank you, man! Much appreciated. I was getting frozen by the ida of re-writing so many figures.